# Get the PR associated with a branch in GitHub API v3

Tags: github-api

If a pull request is open for a branch X, if you attempt to create a new pull request for this branch, GitHub will raise an error.

This gives rise to the following question: given a branch X, is there a way to get the pull request associated with it?